# YouTube Playlist - Change Starting Video + Mobile Support

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, youtube, youtube-api

To embed a playlist, I use the following HTML code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLcld7bnZTdpiTel3p6QbXKIb5i5Wontd0&autoplay=1&iv_load_policy=3&hl=de_DE" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to start e.g. by a specified video ID of the playlist. YouTube uses a parameter (for example &v=60MQ3AG1c8o) behind the playlist id to load e.g. the second video for sharing propose.
Is there a way, to load a specific video of the playlist. So the user is for example able to start directly with the second video and continue with the regular playlist.

If you have a better idea to present video playlists on web applications, please let me know.

The second question/issue I've got is, that it isn't possible on iOS or Android to play the youtube playlist in mobile browsers. Is there any known workaround, to make this possible for mobile devices?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can replace `videoseries` with the video ID to start with, like `0-7IHOXkiV8`:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/0-7IHOXkiV8?list=PLcld7bnZTdpiTel3p6QbXKIb5i5Wontd0&autoplay=1&iv_load_policy=3&hl=de_DE" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to load a playlist and start at a specific position if you use the full YouTube Player API, instead of just an `<iframe>` tag. Here's an example ([jsfiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffposnick/N36vX/4/)):

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'videoseries',
        events: {
            onReady: loadPlaylist
        }
    });
}

function loadPlaylist() {
    player.loadPlaylist({
        list: "PLhBgTdAWkxeCMHYCQ0uuLyhydRJGDRNo5",
        listType: "playlist",
        index: 4
    });
}
```

That *should* work, but it's not right now; I'm going to follow up with the YouTube Players engineering team about why it's not starting playback at the video with index 4.

Comment: Adding that function loadPlaylist() does work for me on Chrome and FireFox. It starts to play the 5th video of that playlist. Seems right when the playlist-index would start with 0.

Comment: I'll give the loadPlaylist() function a try!
Any idea to make it on mobile Chrome and Safari to work?

Comment: Okay, it's actually only broken with HTML5 playback. When you're using Flash playback, it works. It still needs to get fixed.

Comment: So let's say, I've to use the ActionScript API for this, right? How can I actually use it? I followed and looked into the guide ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference ), but I can't find information about JS script to use in my HTML template.

Or do I only have to use the auth.js ? If not, where do I get all other necessary files?

Thanks!

Comment: @user2784727 The above answer has a link to a working example, named: "jsfiddle version". The example shows to include a script file by adding the line: <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

Comment: Am I the only one who can't open the jsfiddle.net website? Chrome reports ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. So I've to use the api script provided by jsfiddle, correct?

Comment: @user2784727 I can see and run the example on jsfiddle.net. I can make a copy of the provided jsfiddle from the above answer into another answer. Show you have a complete page as example. Then delete that answer afterwards. Without the script, you have to change the iframe yourself.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Unfortunately the player size no longer fits perfectly. I used fitvids ( http://fitvidsjs.com/ ) what exactly scales down my video vom 1280x720 to your optimal browser size. It keeps the correct 16:9 aspect ratio and the player stays centered in the middle. With the loadPlaylist function (JS) this no longer works correctly. Do you have any idea, how I can use fitvid's features on this case?

Comment: Any idea to combine it with fitvids to scale the video player correctly?

Comment: Did they updated the YouTube iframe API? Unfortunately it's no longer working and I can't fix the problem by myself. Do you have any clue to start the player with the given index value?

Answer (score 0):

This answer contains a copy of the fiddle from the other answer, as some can't open the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>
            YT video player
        </title>
        <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'videoseries',
        events: {
            onReady: loadPlaylist
        }
    });
}

function loadPlaylist() {
    player.loadPlaylist({
        list: "PLhBgTdAWkxeCMHYCQ0uuLyhydRJGDRNo5",
        listType: "playlist",
        index: 4
    });
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
          <div id="player"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```